# React Fullcalendar v4 tooltip

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, tooltip, popper.js, fullcalendar-4

Fullcalendar React component:

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import timeGrid from "@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid";
import resourceDayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-daygrid';

class FC extends React.Component {
  calendarComponentRef = React.createRef();

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.state = {
        events:[{ "id": 1, "title": "event 1", "description":"some description"},......]
    }  
  }

  eventRender(info){
    var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
      title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'hover',
      container: 'body'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <FullCalendar                  
          events={this.state.getEvents}          
          defaultView="resourceTimeGridDay"
      plugins={[timeGrid, interactionPlugin, resourceDayGridPlugin]}
          eventRender={this.eventRender}
          schedulerLicenseKey="GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source"
        />

  }
}
```

Tooltip.js included in header

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script rc="https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js">/script>
```

Exactly trying to this [demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo) in react, but it is not working in react version.

But tooltip not working

Fullcalendar react example project [sample project react fullcalendar](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/blob/master/react/src/DemoApp.jsx)

Comment: Have you bound your function with your component yet?

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle link for me to have a look into this?

Comment: @FrankAK yes done

Comment: Can you make a minimal, reproducible example please, ideally using CodePen or JSFiddle or something. It's impossible to tell what is wrong from the tiny amount of out-of-context code posted here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance on what to include

Comment: first thing to verify is, is the `eventRender()` function definitely being executed? You can add a log command, or use the debugger to find out. Then we can narrow it down to issues with the tooltip directly

Comment: Secondly, you haven't shown it above, but did you add the necessary CSS for the tooltips? There seems to be no file available for it, but if you look in the CodePen which is linked to from the [fullcalendar tooltip demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo) you'll see there is some CSS written in there which is required for the tooltips to be visible.

Comment: @ADyson 1) I can see the info details inside eventRender 2) Css included for Fullcalendar. there is no css for tooltip

Comment: Well you need CSS for the tooltip, otherwise it will not show up. Like I said, you can get relevant CSS from the CodePen demo (see link in my last comment - from there, click to view in CodePen, and then look in the CSS part of the CodePen)

Comment: @ADyson You are correct. I missed the CSS. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson,
yes, i includes css and js files, but it's not working on my side.
instead of that, i got warning in console.

CalendarDataManager.ts:669 Unknown option 'eventRender'

Comment: @ninjadev1030 if you have a specific problem in your own code, you'll need to ask a new question about it. We cannot be sure what is wrong exactly unless we see more details. Please refer to this question with a link, if you have been trying one of the solutions from it or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tooltip using `Tooltip.js`

```
eventRender(info){
    var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
      title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'hover',
      container: 'body'
    });
  }
```

In component :

```
render() {
    return <FullCalendar                  
          events={this.state.getEvents}          
          defaultView="resourceTimeGridDay"
      plugins={[timeGrid, interactionPlugin, resourceDayGridPlugin]}
          eventRender={this.eventRender}
          schedulerLicenseKey="GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source"
        />

  }
```

OR

using [react-tooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip)

```
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip'
```

and method to handle `eventPosition`

```
handleEventPositioned(info) {
  info.el.setAttribute("data-tip","some text tip");
   ReactTooltip.rebuild();
 }
```

and

```
render() {
        return <FullCalendar                  
              events={this.state.getEvents}          
              defaultView="resourceTimeGridDay"
          plugins={[timeGrid, interactionPlugin, resourceDayGridPlugin]}
              eventPositioned={this.handleEventPositioned}
              schedulerLicenseKey="GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source"
            />

      }
```

Comment: it's not working on my side.
when I tried to implement you, it's still not working.

Comment: `react-tooltip` not working for me (using fullcalendar v5)

Comment: Where's the tooltip.js coming from? I too am trying to implement the tooltip functionality inside my Calendar and I'm using React.

Comment: Please mention which React Fullcalendar version you are using for handleEventPositioned(info) {
  info.el.setAttribute("data-tip","some text tip");
   ReactTooltip.rebuild();
 }

Answer (score 11):

## FullCalendar v5

With [content injection hook](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection) e.g. for [Material-ui tooltip](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/):

```js
eventContent: ( arg ) => {
    return (
        <Tooltip title={ <Typography color="inherit">Tooltip with HTML</Typography> } arrow>
            { renderInnerContent( arg ) }
        </Tooltip>
    );
}
```

If you want to have the exact same content as the default, then copy the function from fullcalendar source:

```js
/**
 * https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/495d925436e533db2fd591e09a0c887adca77053/packages/common/src/common/StandardEvent.tsx#L79
 */
function renderInnerContent( innerProps ) {
    return (
        <div className='fc-event-main-frame'>
            { innerProps.timeText &&
            <div className='fc-event-time'>{ innerProps.timeText }</div>
            }
            <div className='fc-event-title-container'>
                <div className='fc-event-title fc-sticky'>
                    { innerProps.event.title || <Fragment>&nbsp;</Fragment> }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

To differentiate `ListView` content from default content you can use this code (given a [Calendar reference](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react) calendarRef):

```
eventContent: ( arg ) => {
    const data = calendarRef.current.getApi().getCurrentData();
    const viewSpec = data.viewSpecs[arg.view.type];
    let innerContent;
    if (viewSpec.component === ListView) {
        /**
         * https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/495d925436e533db2fd591e09a0c887adca77053/packages/list/src/ListViewEventRow.tsx#L55
         */
        innerContent = renderListInnerContent( arg );
    } else {
        innerContent = renderInnerContent( arg );
    }
    return ( <Tooltip ... >{ innerContent }</Tooltip>);
};
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this addition. Is there any way to import this from the lib so it's not copied and pasted?

Comment: Unfotunately haven't made any progress in that direction. Lib does not export these components or provide access to the default one: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5927

Comment: If your package updates with new CSS for those "fc" classes, but the HTML remains the same, it may cause some issues later down the line.

Answer (score 3):

Tooltip using [tippy](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) with eventMouseEnter

```
    handleMouseEnter = (arg) =>{
    tippy(arg.el, {
        content: "my tooltip!"
    });
}
```

in component

```
render() {
    return (
            <FullCalendar ref={this.calendarRef}
                          plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                          initialView="dayGridMonth"
                          weekends={true}
                          eventMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}

            />
    )
}
```

Comment: While I don't think an answer requiring a 3rd party package should be THE answer, this is the best answer in terms of simplicity and lack of potential bugs that will come from using the currently picked answer (requiring keeping track of source code)

Answer (score 1):

Best I did so far. This will at least give a title to an event.

```
<FullCalendar eventDidMount={renderEventContent} .....

function renderEventContent(info) {
  info.el.setAttribute('title', info.event.title)
}
```